# Pay any 3rd party via Stripe

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments, credit-card

I'm hoping for a step in the right direction for the following.

I need to be able to pay anyone a fixed amount via Stripe, even though I may have not charged them or have their details or any existing token with their card details.

That is, either credit someone's credit card, or make a bank transfer into their account for an account I specify.

The best use case I can share is something similar to a cash give away where you sign up and receive money.

I've looked at Stripe connect and transferring funds via the API, but I believe this assumes you already have a user in your stripe system, i.e you need stripe token. (https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-connect-vs-sending-transfers-via-api)

Has anyone tried this implementation via Stripe before?

Are there any other recommendations via other payment processors, eg: Paypal.

I should add, I'd be transferring into Australian bank accounts.

Comment: I've posted an answer to a duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841041/does-stripe-allow-to-give-money-to-customers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Stripe has an equivalent option, but with PayPal you can use the [DoNonReferencedCredit](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/) API to deposit money onto somebody's credit card.